# How to get every row which has one of several specified ids?

Tags: mysql, database, where-clause, where-in

I have a list`(1,2,3,4,5,20,25,27)` etc of `id` values. I would like to get all the rows which have any one of these values.

So I decided to get it with `WHERE` Clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, IF(c.image IS NULL, "default.png", c.image), 
c.first_name, c.email_primary, c.contact_mobile, c.contact_home, 
c.last_name, c.contact_work, cn.country_name, c.unique_id, c.title, 
cm.name, 
SUBSTRING(c.first_name, 1, 1), IF(s.id IS NULL, "0", "1") flag_already_synced, 
GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag) contact_tag_names, sector, c.salutation, c.email_secondry,
c.email_work, c.contact_work, REPLACE(c.assistant_name, "\r\n", ""), 
c.city, h.honorofic, REPLACE(c.contact_owner, "\r\n", ""), c.created_on, c.gender, c.flag_vip 
FROM (`contact` c) 
LEFT JOIN `country` cn ON `cn`.`id`=`c`.`country_id` 
LEFT JOIN `sync` s ON `s`.`contact_id` = `c`.`id` AND s.user_id = 29 
LEFT JOIN `contact_tag` ct ON `ct`.`contact_id` = `c`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `tag_master` t ON `ct`.`tag_id` = `t`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `honorfic` h ON `h`.`id` = `c`.`honorfic` 
LEFT JOIN ( select company_id,contact_id from 
contact_company where flag_primary = "Y" AND flag_delete = "0" order by 
created_on desc ) as cc ON `c`.`id`=`cc`.`contact_id` 
LEFT JOIN `company` cm ON `cm`.`id`=`cc`.`company_id` 
WHERE `c`.`flag_delete` = '0' 
AND (c.flag_vip=0 or 
c.flag_vip=1 or c.flag_vip= 2) 
AND `c`.`guest_of` IS NULL AND `c`.`id` IN ( 
'1','2','3','4','5','20','25','27' ) 
LIMIT 50
```

But I am getting only one row, which has an `id` equal to 1. What should I do to get all rows with any of the requested `id` values?

`c.id IN ( '1','2','3','4','5','20','25','27' )` Doesn't seems to get all the row which has the above `id`s`

**EDIT**

After suggestion from comment I have removed all other WHERE clause condition and left with `c.id IN ( 1,2,3,4,5,20,25,27 )` But still I get only one row.

Comment: Code formatted @Timeout

Comment: Are you doing this in a shell, phpmyadmin, with php code, other? Are you sure the other conditions of the WHERE clause don't filter out the other ids? Does this work if you change the `c.id IN ...` to say, `(c.id = 1 OR c.id = 2 OR ...`?

Comment: Have you tried without quotes on the integer IDs ?

Comment: Remove every other condition in WHERE clause and see if it returns your ids. I'd assume there are other conditions that prevent those row from appearing in the result, or simply that there are no rows with such id. If your contact(id) field is a number do not use inverted commas around values - this is reserved for character types.

Comment: @ConsiderMe I removed every other condition in WHERE clause, still I get only one row. There are rows with such id. I have removed quotation too. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Terminus I tried  `(c.id = 1 OR c.id = 2 OR ... ` still I get only one row

Comment: Do you get more than one row if you remove the `WHERE` clause all together? What do you get when you change your `SELECT` list to `DISTINCT c.id`?

Comment: @rram Show your full query after changes. Also show us result of `select distinct id from contact where id IN(...)` your list.

Comment: HI all Thanks for your suggestion. I just wanted to let you all know that the problem is solved by adding order_by c.id in the query. After adding the order_by I can able to get all rows with the ids.